# oracle sql how to select specific distinct set in group by function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Table

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Col1               | Col2                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| A                  | 1                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| A                  | 2                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| A                  | 3                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| B                  | 3                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| B                  | 4                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| B                  | 5                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| C                  | 4                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| C                  | 6                         |
--------------------------------------------------
| C                  | 3                         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

how to select distinct col1 that has 3 and 4 (answer is B, C)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `IN` clauses (or `EXISTS`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
FROM Table
WHERE 
COL1 IN (SELECT Col1 FROM Table WHERE Col2 = 3)
AND
COL1 IN (SELECT Col1 FROM Table WHERE Col2 = 4)
```

Or this `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT Col1 FROM Table
WHERE Col2 IN (3,4)
GROUP BY Col1
HAVNG COUNT(DISTINCT Col2) = 2
```

Comment: the 2nd query was what i was looking for, it was much faster (large table) thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcc99/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (Col1, Col2 ) AS
          SELECT 'A', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', 2 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'A', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 3 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'B', 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 4 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 6 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBERs_Table AS TABLE OF NUMBER(1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT   Col1
FROM     tbl
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING   NUMBERs_Table(3,4) SUBMULTISET OF CAST( COLLECT( Col2 ) AS NUMBERs_Table )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bcc99/4/0)**:

```
| COL1 |
|------|
|    B |
|    C |
```